# Binding configuration to a function using a closure

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm reading through [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) on reusable charts in d3, and in the first "Configuration" section, the author describes two ways of making a chart function:

```
// Method 1
function chart(config) {
  // generate chart here, using `config.width` and `config.height`
}

// Method 2
function chart(config) {
  return function() {
    // generate chart here, using `config.width` and `config.height`
  };
}
```

He suggests the second method over the first, because

> However, the caller must then manage both the chart function (assuming you have multiple types of charts to pick from) and the configuration object. To bind the chart configuration to the chart function, we need a closure.

I don't understand this explanation, though. What are the advantages of method 2 over the first method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about managing information. In the first case, if you want to change the configuration of the chart, the caller has to remember that `config` has to be passed to `chart`:

```
chart(config);
config.xy = 42;
// update the chart, calling chart again
chart(config);
```

Now, if there are multiple, potentially different, charts (and therefor different chart functions, like `barchart`, `linechart`, etc), the caller has to remember which configuration to pass to which function.

It would be easier if the "type" of the chart would be self-contained somehow. In the second example, you get back a reference to a function which knows how to update the chart you just created. So you can update the chart without knowing which function it was created by:

```
var myChart = chart(config);
config.xy = 42;
// update the chart
myChart();
```

This seems to be an approach that D3 uses, but you could also use an object-oriented approach, i.e. creating a proper `Chart` constructor function which encapsulates the logic to render and update a chart.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that I've found that is even better than the two you've listed - something I picked up from the d3 source code:

```
function chart() {
    var width, height;

    function display() {
        console.log("My dimensions are: (" + width + " x " + height + ").");
    }

    display.width = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return width;
        width = value;
        return display;
    };

    display.height = function(value) { 
        if (!arguments.length) return height;
        height = value;
        return display;
    };

    return display;    
}

var config = {width: 5, height: 10},
    myChart = chart().width(config.width).height(config.height);

console.log("Width:", myChart.width());   // Width: 5
console.log("Height:", myChart.height()); // Height: 10
myChart(); // My dimensions are (5 x 10).
myChart.height(5);
myChart(); // My dimensions are (5 x 5).
```